# Объединить одинаковые элементы в многомерном массиве

Tags: массивы, search

Есть многомерный массив:

```
Array(
0 => Array(0 => 'S', 1 => '#000'),
1 => Array(0 => 'S', 1 => '#fff'),
2 => Array(0 => 'XL', 1 => '#fff')
)
```

В итоге нужно получить строки такого вида:
S = #000, #fff
XL = #fff

Comment: Строку или строки?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov строки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = array(
  0 => array(0 => 'S', 1 => '#000'),
  1 => array(0 => 'S', 1 => '#fff'),
  2 => array(0 => 'XL', 1 => '#fff')
);

// Сливаем все одинаковые значения в один подмассив
$join = [];
foreach ($data as $val) {
  if (!isset($join[$val[0]])
    $join[$val[0]] = [];
  $join[$val[0]][] = $val[1];
}

// Соединяем все значения из подмассивов
foreach ($join as $key => $val)
  printf('%s = %s', $key, implode(', ', $val));
```